# Understanding transformed data (PCA transformation )

Tags: python, data-science, data-analysis, pca

Is it possible to understand the new dataset features obtained after applying PCA transformation to it?
clarification:
A dataset contains only numerical input variables resulting from a PCA transformation,
Features V1, V2, … V28 are the principal components obtained with PCA
it there any possibility of understanding the Features V1, V2, … V28 !!!

the dataset link:https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/mlg-ulb/creditcardfraud

Comment: You can find a whole lot about this on the internet. Have you tried googling about interpretability of PCA?

Comment: we are on the internet, by the way, though I tried my best googling  about it

Comment: do you have any clues?

Comment: PCA dimensions are simply linear combinations of input dimensions, so you can express the new features as a weighted sum of old features with the transformation coefficients if I'm not mistaken